# How messages from printf are routed to the terminal?

Tags: stdout, pty, terminal-emulator

Lets say I have opened two tabs in the konsole (Tab1 and Tab2).

When I run tty in both of them I have:

Tab1:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pts/23
```

Tab2:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pts/24
```

If I run a simple program hello.c with a printf("Hello") in Tab1, how the system goes from writing to the stdout (file id 1) to writing to /dev/pts/23, being read by the konsole and then appearing in Tab1?

How the system know it has to give the "Hello" string to /dev/pts/23 and not to /dev/pts/24? And how it does that?

Is there a parameter given by the bash to the program so it knows which psudoterminal to send the "Hello"? Or the program sends the string back to the bash (how?) who knows to which pseudoterminal to send the data?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The set of open files is local to every process. The shell has a specific pseudo-terminal device open in the stdin/out/err slots, which get inherited by the child processes when spawned. The pseudo-terminal itself is essentially a named pipe allocated by the system call and which the x-terminal, or whatever you are using, is reading text from the other end of and printing to the screen. [This is a good read](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your process open files, you can see that the STDOUT,STDERR, etc points to the specific psuedo terminal that you already figured out using `tty` in your question

```
root@hello:~# ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 2 -> /dev/pts/3
```

As you might know, a process is created by a `fork` system call that actually duplicates the open file descriptors from the parent. so basically, your process gets the file descriptors from its parent.

How did the parent hot these associated with him ? well, `konsole` already dealt with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When I do ls -l /proc/self/fd, how the kernel knows from which terminal I am making this call? Why this output is different in every konsole tab?

Comment: Search the net for `controlling terminal`. Start here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html